# how do i access the acorn and acorn-walk from the process object

Tags: node.js, process, abstract-syntax-tree, acorn

I am looking at the lastest version of the nodejs. https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/51342 how do i access the acorn and acorn-walk from the process object and how do i access the "AST of the node process" from nodejs.

try this - you will find acorn in the deps.

```
console.log(process)
```

access the acorn and acorn-walk from the process object to access the AST of the process. Is it read only or allows manipulating code from the process object.